# How to get 3D building view in map view in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-mapview

I used the map setting,

```
googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
```

But it's not working.
About a month ago, it was working fine. Attaching the screenshot for ref.

This is the view I was getting a month ago.

[image]

Now map shows 2D view.

[image]

Comment: Try zooming in a bit, it doesn't show buildings if you're zoomed out too far.

Comment: Yes, have already done that. Changed zoom level to 19, still it didn't work.

Comment: Are you at the same location as you were a month ago when it was working?  If you are at a different location, it's possible that there is no building data there.

Comment: Yes, I have tried for all those locations where it used to show 3D view.