# How to enable 3D buildings in Google Maps API? (2018)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to view buildings in 3D in Google Maps and everything else I've searched on this seems to be outdated and no longer functional. Currently I have

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(true);

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng steubenville = new LatLng(40.377139, -80.623639);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(steubenville).title("Welcome to Franciscan University!"));
    float zoomLevel = 16.0f; //This goes up to 21
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(steubenville, zoomLevel));
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```

All I have really found online is to add

```
 mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
mMap.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(true);
```

And yet that doesn't change anything on my map. The purpose of this is to zoom in on the map at the press of a button and see the 3D buildings at an angle.

Comment: set the zoom level to 17 or higher

Comment: That simply zooms in further into the map and doesn't make it 3D...

Comment: It looks like you will also need to be looking at a place that has data to support the 3D view, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44268824/how-to-get-3d-building-view-in-map-view-in-android

Comment: There's no solution for him either

Comment: Test your code over downtown San Francisco to see if it's working, that's the best you can do.

Comment: @DanielNugent Update, the buildings are 3D in normal view but not in Satellite view...

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting to see in satellite view... even the main Google Maps app doesn't show 3D buildings in satellite view.

Comment: You're very right..The desktop version does...Any clue on how to link it up as a web app so I can show it on mobile?